# Loop through every combination of a large 2D Array

Tags: c#

In my program I have a 2D Array of objects as such:

```
Component[,] layout = new Component[19,16];
```

There are 3 possibilities as to what a Component can be.

```
0 - Empty
1 - Cell
2 - Vent
```

I need to programmatically generate a possible permutation for this 2D Array, then run it through a method, then generate the next permutation.

I need to generate every possible permutation without getting the same one twice.

I would use nested for loops but that would require 304 loops nested within each other, which I'd rather not do.

Currently I'm using the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                Component comp;
                int rand = rng.Next(0, 3);

                switch (rand)
                {
                    case 1:
                        comp = Component.Cell;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        comp = Component.Vent;
                        break;
                    default:
                        comp = null;
                        break;
                }

                Components[i, j] = comp;
            }
        }
```

(rng is a custom handler for RNGCryptoServiceProvider)

This code simply generates random permutations, but has no way of checking if that permutation has been generated before, and I'd rather not store a list of all previously used permutations.

Is there any reasonable way to do this?

EDIT: After looking at the comments, and based on the intended use of this program, I've decided a genetic algorithm is in fact the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: By every possible permutation you mean every possible way of setting every cell in a 19x16 grid to one of 3 states?  If so you aren't going to run through every one.  Your life isn't long enough.

Comment: Define "possible permutation". Are you aware that if you were able to produce 1 billion permutations a second it would take about 3.5e128 years to produce them all if there are no rules governing what a "possible permutation" is?

Comment: Also note that there is no way to keep such a list either, there simply is not enough storage available in all of mankinds computers, now or future.

Comment: There is no reasonable way to do this, since 3^304 is around 10^144, and there are only about 10^17 seconds in the age of the universe. But I see others have beat me to this comment...

Comment: **Why** do you need to generate all possible permutations? Knowing that might indicate other ways of accomplishing your goal.

Comment: The program is intended to be a "simulator" of sorts for a game. The game features a 19x16 grid where you can place Fuel Cells (Nuclear fuel IE Uranium cells), Heat Vents, Power Capacitors etc etc. The hope is that this program can be used to help calculate the most efficient possible layouts for the game.

Comment: Sounds like a random search is a good option.  It depends on the definition of "best", in some cases genetic algorithm may work well. So take a starting state, mutate it randomly slightly to produce several "children", select the "best", repeat. In simple terms this works if the "bestness" of a state is in some way a smooth function of the value of the state, so you can incrementally approach local maximums of "bestness"

Comment: Are there _any_ constraints, e.g. placing more than 42 fuel cells together may result in an undesirable case of prompt criticality? That might let you prune the search tree somewhat.

Comment: @JamesGaunt That sounds like the best option (genetic algorithm) but I have no idea how to go about doing that. The "Bestness" of the layout is an easily measurable absolute (in the form of a number indicating the layout's power output) but the maximum "Bestness" is unknown, and there are certain other simple factors that would label a layout as a failure (Too much heat causing vents to overheat or the reactor to meltdown) Any pointers to help me in the right direction on making a genetic algorithm?

Comment: I'll post an answer to expand.  I'm in no way an expert on genetic algorithms but the basic idea is quite simple and you've done the hard work, it's a small improvement on testing random states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider a genetic algorithm, as searching the entire space of all possible options isn't feasible.

The basic approach is:

- Pick a starting state randomly (as you are doing)
- Generate X child states which are small perturbations on the starting state. A perturbation is just a small change on the parent state.  For example randomly change a small number of cells
- From this set of children pick the "best"
- Repeat

You would generally stop when you found the improvement from generation to generation was below a certain threshold.

The algorithm of course relies on having a numerical value of "bestness" to compare from child to child and generation to generation.

It's usually quite quick to perform a search using this algorithm. But you have to remember all you are doing is finding local maximums, i.e. local best solutions near your start solution.  So often you run the computation again and again with different starting solutions.

It's like landing at a random point in a hilly landscape and only walking up. You arrive at a peak eventually, and usually quite quickly - but it may not be the highest peak in the entire mountain range.

However this won't work if your measure of "bestness" does not change reasonably smoothly with the position in the space of all possible states.  Imagine a chaotic, jagged landscape with cliffs the vertical walls, moving a small amount may not result in a close value of "bestness".

Comment: Alright, so my idea is that I "mutate" until I find a successful layout (one that doesn't overheat), then I mutate that, only counting successful child states, and continue like that.

Comment: If your measure of "bestness" is binary (success/failure) it won't work. You  need a scale of measures really.  If you can picture the smooth vs jagged landscape idea - you need smooth(ish) rolling hills.

Comment: One possibility though - perhaps you can measure the time taken to overheat.  A long time is better than a short time for example.  The success of this kind of algorithm is really totally tied to the underlying process you are simulating.

Comment: The measure of "bestness" is power output, but the layout also has to succeed.
The resulting layout that is ultimately outputed as the "best" possible layout should be able to run infinitely without overheating.

Comment: It sounds like that involves a lot of calculations to arrive at a measure of "bestness".  To work you have to be able to search the space quickly.  All you can really do is try.  Perhaps first focus on just searching for high power output if that is quick to calculate - although it sounds like high power output is going to be closely related to overheating.  At the end of the day you know if the search is "working" if it regularly finds optimal solutions (i.e. it settles down to a state where all states close to it are worse or only better to within threshold).

Answer (score 0):

Your 2D array 19by16 can be also represented as 1D array of length 19x16=304
so if I understand correctly u need to generate for example strings of length 304
where all possible values of single character is 0 or 1 or 2
simple for can generate this and you can be sure not to have same result twice.
After genereting its simple task to fill it in 2D array